# jQuery .on() function - advance selector used as "selector" parameter?

Tags: jquery, button, iframe, selector, bind

I am using the  [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind a event on button that is located in frame. Because the button, can be rendered in the future i am using the following syntax:

```
$('#myIframe').contents().on('click','.myButton img[src="/myImage.gif"]',function(){

});
```

But what I met as a great issue is that I am selecting the button by its class and source attribute value as follows:

```
$('.myButton img[src="/myImage.gif"]').parent()
```

How can I add this "parent()" part in the on. function "selector" parameter? Is it possible at all?

Note, I am not able to change the content of the frame as adding id to the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do `.parent()`, however it is possible to use `:has()`

```
'.myButton:has(img[src="/myImage.gif"])'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer and the nice workaround. Anyway, it is a bit disappointing that I am not able to use more complex selectors as parameter.

Comment: .parent() isn't a selector. That's the problem. In that parameter, you aren't selecting elements, you are telling jQuery what selector the event.target must match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent as a selector:

http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/

so you're selector would be:

```
$('.myButton img[src="/myImage.gif"]:parent')
```

Comment: This would select all images that are children of myButton and that are also parents. Since images can't be parents, this will select nothing.

Comment: yes, I didn't read that through. But you can use :parent as a selector. Just doesn't work in this case.